# How is this person purposely failing transactions on this sidechain?

Tags: web3js, ether, web3.py, sidechain

so I am using a ethereum side chain to develop on, however I have found what seems to be a bot doing something that I thought was impossible. It seems that they are purposely failing their transactions if they are being approved in a block that they do not want to be approved in. As soon as their condition is met, they allow approval of their transaction.

Example of NFT Listing at block (9349443) -https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x22cb5d1abde989ec94a385b93bccb25c8c8c5cc442ccec8dd44dcd0c8a8bf695

Example of the first failed transaction at block (9349449) - https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x6e1368dc7fb589859cafd978bd8f2a9f4e845478c1dfc812c24bfa34ec3ab1dd

Example of successful transaction at block (9349452) - https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0x1a93d0030ea4d2b8ecead2c8a14d3f8fa52f919b97893bfda5dfdb39298a0395

In this scenario they are waiting for a block that is greater than 7 blocks. As soon as they see that 7 blocks have passed since the auction listing, they allow their transactions to be approved.
How are they doing this?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The bot may be sending their transactions through a smart contract. The contract may call the Buy NFT function on the auction contract and then include a 'require' that block.number == a specific block, otherwise reverts.